# ReSharper want to still import Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls

Tags: xaml, resharper, win-universal-app

I created new project in Visual Studio - Universal Windows. Why ReSharper still want to import Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls ?
[image]

Do you have any idea ? It's burdensome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. The problem waslocalized in VS Extensions Manager which said that my ReSharper is up to date. After installed new version from ReSharper official web site everything is right.